# Snake in C - Integer gets changed without being changed - what's the problem?

Tags: c, arrays

(program language is c - when correcting please only use stuff noobs can do, I am just learning this since 1 week)

The problem is: See the "int snakelen = 1;" at the start of main?

I never change that integer. But when I end the game it is 0. Why?

And if i TRY TO CHANGE snakelen mid-game, the game completely breaks and i get windows-error sounds.
What's the matter?

(And the food doesnt spawn randomly although i use a randomizer. And it either spawns bottom-only or top-only - changing about every 5 minutes. another wierd glitch.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 2048 //32(*2 because every 2nd one is a space) * 32
#define HSIZE 1024 //32 * 32
#define UP_ 1
#define DOWN_ 3
#define LEFT_ 4
#define RIGHT_ 2
#define YSIZE 64 //length of a row (including spaces)

//TO PLAY: Start the game once, right-click the command-promt at the top, click Settings -> Layout . Then change the window size to 64 (hor) * 33 (vert)

int counter = 0;
int gamespeed = 400;//Intervall in which a game-frame gets rendered

int spawnfood(int* freetable, int snakelen)
{
    srand ( time(NULL) ); //randomize
    int randomIndex = rand()%(HSIZE - 1); //take random non-x-filled position from array
    int randomValue = freetable[randomIndex]; //output the random position
    return randomValue;
}

int main()
{
    int nofood = 1; //is there food in the game? 1 = no
    //int tmp = 0; //temporary memory for later
    int tmp2 = 0; //temporary memory2
    int snakelen = 1; //length of snake
    int snakedir = RIGHT_; //Position the snake is looking
    int snakeheadxpos = 0; //x-position of snake
    int snakeheadypos = 0; //y-position of snake
    char q;//The button that was pressed last


    char gametable[SIZE]; //the game-screen //fill it with spaces
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        gametable[i]=' ';
    }
    gametable[SIZE] = '\0';


    int freetable[(HSIZE)]; // 32*32 list of all pixels, which shows whether a pixel is an x or not
    for(int i = 0; i < (HSIZE); i++)
    {
        freetable[i]= i*2; //fill the array with its numbers
    }


    //START OF GAME
    printf("Press any Button to start the game!\n");
    getch();
    for(int i = 0; i < 31; i++){
        printf("\n");
    }

    while(q != 27)
    {
        counter++;
        if(kbhit()) //if button is pressed
        {
            q = getch(); //q = that button
            switch(q) //change the way the snake looks via WASD
            {
            case 'w':
                if(snakedir != DOWN_)
                    snakedir = UP_;
                break;
            case 'a':
                if(snakedir != RIGHT_)
                    snakedir = LEFT_;
                break;
            case 's':
                if(snakedir != UP_)
                    snakedir = DOWN_;
                break;
            case 'd':
                if(snakedir != LEFT_)
                    snakedir = RIGHT_;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
        if(counter%gamespeed == 0) //Renders a game-frame at the intervall of gamespeed
        {
            switch(snakedir)
            {

            case UP_:
                if(snakeheadypos==0)
                {
                    goto exit_loop; //ran into a wall
                }
                snakeheadypos--;
                break;

            case DOWN_:
                if(snakeheadypos==31)
                {
                    goto exit_loop; //ran into a wall
                }
                snakeheadypos++;
                break;

            case RIGHT_:
                if(snakeheadxpos==31)
                {
                    goto exit_loop; //ran into a wall
                }
                snakeheadxpos++;
                break;

            case LEFT_:
                if(snakeheadxpos==0)
                {
                    goto exit_loop; //ran into a wall
                }
                snakeheadxpos--;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            if((gametable[snakeheadypos*YSIZE + 2*snakeheadxpos] == 'o'))
            {
                //snakelen++; //<-- WHEN YOU REMOVE THE FIRST //, THE GAME STARTS TO BUG AND I GET WINDOWS ERROR SOUNDS!
                nofood = 1; //no more food is in the game
            }
            gametable[snakeheadypos*YSIZE + 2*snakeheadxpos] = 'x'; //set the pixel ur at the the moment to 'x'

            gametable[tmp2] =' ';
            tmp2 = snakeheadypos*64+snakeheadxpos*2;
            //spawn food if there is none
            if(nofood)
            {
                gametable[spawnfood(freetable, snakelen)] = 'o';
                nofood = 0; //food is already placed
            }
            printf("%s", gametable); // print the gametable
        }
    }
exit_loop: ; //if you ran into a wall
    printf("Game Over - Score: %d", snakelen);
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using `goto` as it makes code more difficult to follow. Don't get into the habit of using it.

Comment: `goto` is the black sheep of programming. Do *not* use it!

Comment: @gsamaras in C goto is sometimes the most  appropriate solution.

Comment: @FiddlingBits do not promote cargo-cult. In C, `goto` is valid and useful.

Comment: @SergeyA If `goto` is the most appropriate solution I'd say you need to refactor/re-architect/modularize your code.

Comment: `gametable[SIZE] = '\0';` Here is some __undefined behavior__. Valid array indices run from `0` to `SIZE-1`

Comment: @FiddlingBits you'd be wrong in saying so ;)

Comment: @SergeyA I think it's a matter of opinion rather than right or wrong.

Comment: @SergeyA I guess it also depends on if it's responsibly used.

Comment: If you can't see a better solution than `goto`... keep looking.

Comment: A switch statement is just an enumerated `goto` construct.  And, how many times have you seen `goto` statements buried in error handling macros? (which is kind of what OP has done here without the macro.)  Just saying, there is still a place for carefully used `goto` statements.

Comment: How can assigning a value to `snakelen` break the code? It doesn't seem to be used. It is passed to `spawnfood()` but there it is ignored. What am I missing?

Comment: @FiddlingBits well, here is an exercise for you - you have a function which needs to use 3 resources, each of which has a step to aquire (initialize) and a step to cleanup. An init can be successful or a failure. Each successfully inited resource **must** be cleaned up, while a resources which failed to initialize must **never** be cleaned up. A function needs to aquire 3 resources in sequence, and perform action iff all of them were aquired successfully. Than whatever was aquired, needs to be cleaned up. How would you design such a function?

Comment: @TimRandall see my question above.

Comment: @SergeyA You make a good point. Like @ryyker mentioned above, I have used a C `TRY`/`FINALLY` macro construct with an embedded `goto`.

Comment: Hey guys, breaking news: goto considered harmful! Lets debate this in the comment field! Never been done before.

Comment: @SergeyA when (s)he grows, (s)he will know. At this stage, it's a solid spartan no.-

Comment: What else should i use then, instead of goto???

Comment: Can't use break; inside a switch function.

Comment: @TimRandall I plan on using snakelen later on. If it changed value mid-game by itself I can not use it. So i thought better find a fix first before using it.

Comment: Later on, you could consider moving the `while` loop into a separate function (called `Game()` perhaps). Then you can use `return` instead of `goto`.

Comment: Great idea, thank you! Will definetly do that in later projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 char gametable[SIZE]; //the game-screen //fill it with spaces
 ...
 gametable[SIZE] = '\0';
```

This is wrong.   You can index an array of size N with indices 0 through N-1.  `gametable[SIZE]` is outside the array, and assigning to it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh :/ In university we were told an array ends in a null-pointer.And as far as i know \0 is a null-pointer. I just use it to make sure the array ends properly. If i remove that line the code doesn't work.

Comment: @FireFuro99 to be fair, though, if you leave the line in, the code doesn't work.

Comment: I changed it to " = NULL". Doesn't change anything tho. snakelen is still 0 at the end. Help.

Comment: @Tim Randall  Ok - the code "works" when i remove that line. It just doesn't work like i expect it to. Well then that might be the problem.

Comment: You cannot safely store **any** value at that array index. It is illegal to do so. It causes **undefined behavior** which means that the program can do anything including nothing at all, crash, corrupt the value of another variable, or halt and catch fire.

Comment: @Tim Randall  I never stored any value there, i know that you cant store values there. I ended the array by placing the null-pointer (not a value), cause in university we learned (if im remember correctly) that an array ends in a null pointer.

Comment: Any expression of the form `array[index]=value;` **does** store a value in the array. This is nothing to do with null pointers. A null pointer is just a pointer whose value is zero, meaning it doesn't point to an object. I think you are mis-remembering something else, which is that strings—arrays of `char`—usually end with a `NUL` terminator. This is a single character—not a pointer—that has a value of zero, which is sometimes written as `'\0'`. But it doesn't matter whether you write it as `0` or `'\0'` or `0x0` or `NULL`, you're storing a value of zero at an array index that is invalid.

Comment: _"In university we were told an array ends in a null-pointer."_ : either you misunderstood something, or it may be time forr your teacher to retire. I suppose rather you've misunderstood something and you're mixing up NUL (nor NULL) terminated strings and and arrays.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. An expression of the form `array[index]=value;` only stores a value in the array __if the index is valid__.

Comment: You were probably not told that an array ends in a null pointer.  A *string* is an array of character with a terminal null value.  The `array[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0}` initializes an array of size 4 which is a string of length 3.  `array[3]` is the nul character.  Attempting to reference `array[4]` is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: This isn't a "give a man a fish" answer. It's a "teach a man to fish' answer.

On every one of your statements that reads or writes to an array, you should check the array index for validity.

For example, instead of

```
gametable[snakeheadypos*YSIZE + 2*snakeheadxpos] = 'x';

gametable[tmp2] =' ';
```

...write...

```
int index;

index=snakeheadypos*YSIZE + 2*snakeheadxpos;
if(index<0 || index >=SIZE){printf("Index error A: value is %d", index);exit(1);}
gametable[index] = 'x';

index=tmp2;
if(index<0 || index >=SIZE){printf("Index error B: value is %d", index);exit(1);}
gametable[index] =' ';
```

This sort of technique can help you detect array index problems, which can be a very common source of bugs, and can produce all sort of weird symptoms.

Comment: It would be better to replace this with a macro which expands to nothing on release builds and checks only on debug builds. It's better to just get used to `array[SIZE+1]` for this anyway, it's almost expected that the `+1` will indicate that the array is both a string that will be used for text and that it will be explicitly nul terminated.

Comment: @PurpleIce yes, you're right about the macro. I was assuming that these checks would be used as temporary development aids only, and would be removed once the bugs were out of the code.

Comment: Didn't get the macro part, but that array[SIZE+1] is a great idea! now i can set array[SIZE] to \0 ! THANKS! :D